# How to write an expression that averages a calculated sum value in a grouped table in SSRS?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I have this grouped table in SSRS. I want to get the average care plan cost for each owner. I want this average to be the average of all their individual client's monthly costs. I cannot figure out the correct expression to do this.

I tried `=Avg((Sum(Fields!Avg_Monthly_Cost.Value)),"Owner_Name")` but it did not populate the correct value.

Here's a screenshot of the table I'm referring to:
[image]
The highlighted expression is what I need help with. I want it to sum the "Sum of Average Monthly Costs for Client's Services" values for each client under each owner.

I want to get the average value of all of `[Sum(Avg_Monthly_Cost)]` that show up under each owner to populate next to the owner's name. This is where I am stuck.

Here are my row groups:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, you say *"I want it to sum the "Sum of Average Monthly Costs for Client's Services" values for each client under each owner"* but your expression is trying to sum values?

If you want to aggregate values that are calculated in a child row group then you need to reference the child group, not the group that the expression resides in.

So if you want the average of those grey `SUM`s then you could do something like

```
=Avg((Sum(Fields!Avg_Monthly_Cost.Value,"FullName")))
```

As the expression is sitting in the `"Owner_Name"` row group it will only 'see' those values in scope ( the child row group data ).

If this does not help, edit your question and show the relevant rowgroups and the expression that you are trying to aggregate.

Comment: I tried that and got this error: The value expression for the text box has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a data set.

Comment: Apologies, I had a `)` in the wrong place, I've edited the expression.

Comment: Now it says [rsComplierErrorInExpression] The value expression for the textrun contains an error:[BC30198]')' expected.

Comment: I've updated it again, I've tested it this time (previously just did it from memory when tired!!). Basically the inner expression needs to be the same as the thing you are trying to sum but with the scope added. The scope must be the scope that the expression you are trying to sum already sits (which looks like "FullName" from your images)

Comment: Thank you that works great!! I also found that this works too.
```=(Avg((Sum(Fields!Avg_Monthly_Cost.Value)),"Owner_Name"))/(CountDistinct(Fields!Client_ID.Value))```